# Highstocks: Disable the Vertical line while hovering on legend or chart

Tags: highcharts

In my chart I have a vertical line displayed every time I hover on the chart, is there any way i can avoid showing the vertical line.
I have already tried plotOptions.series.enableMouseTracking option, it works but it disable the click event on each points. I can't disable the click event.
I am using Highstock JS v5.0.9[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable [crosshair](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.crosshair) on the xAxis to get rid of that line.

Like this:

```
xAxis: {
  crosshair: false
},
```

**JSFiddle example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/5uxwy926/3/